# SSRS - Changing tab name when exporting to excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have tabbed my report in SSRS 2012 by having my page breaks based upon grouping `classname` and it works great. How do I change the tab names when exporting to Excel? I tried having an expression for page name `=Fields!classname.Value`. In doing so, it makes all 4 of my tabs equal the first page break of `Sales Division`.

My tabs are based upon the grouping of `classname`, which in returns gives me the 4 tabs: `Sales Division`, `VRS`, `ClearCaptions`, and `IP-relay`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution was not working for me.

I had to add group break page.

[image]

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3527/export-sql-server-reporting-services-report-data-into-multiple-excel-worksheets/

Answer (score 61):

You need to set the `PageName` of the Tablix **Member** (group), **NOT** the `PageName` of the Tablix **itselfs**. 
If you got the right object, if will say "Tablix **Member**" (Tablix-Element in German) in the title box of the properties grid. If it's the wrong object, it will say **only** "table/tablix" (without *member*).
Also, be advised to set the sort order of the group expression, so the tabs are alphabetically sorted.

If you get the tablix instead of the tablix member, it will put the same tab name in every tab, followed by a `(tabNum)`. That is exactly your current problem.

[image: Tablix Member]

[image: MultiTabExcelFile]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This helped me solve the same issue and clarified the confusion of having to select the Tablix Member instead of the Tablix itself.

Comment: This works for the first tablix in a report. The second tablix will use the PageName from the first tablix with a number in parentheses appended.

Comment: @TKK: You can also set the page-name to an expression, then you can get the tab's name from the database for every tab. Note that the (stupid) excel-limit for tab-names is 31 characters.

Comment: You have to expand the **[+}Group** to see the **PageName** in the properties window. Which makes it unnecessarily hard to find by browsing around.